# Change font size and Bold text in output using xlswrite

Tags: excel, matlab, text

I write many worksheets in a file using `xlswrite`. I want to change font size and type to bold for contents of cell A1, AB1, and a few more cells. It seems like I will have to download a fancier version of `xlswrite` to accomplish this. Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: Do you mind if the solution uses VBA - it is much simpler to do this within excel after you execute `xlswrite`

Comment: Yes, this function looks like it might do what you want: http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8345-xlswritespec

Answer (score -1):

Feel free to disagree.
IMHO, you can get this requirement done, by utilizing Excel VBA after you execute the `xlswrite`.
Here is the VBA script for this. Run the script after you have the data inside Excel.

```
Sub Macro1()
Range("A3:A10").Select    'You can specify your range here
With Selection.Font
    .Size = 14
    .Bold = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Whilst this may work, I think a better solution is to do it all in one go during the `xlswrite` operation so that you only have to operate in MATLAB and not faff around with VBA in Excel. Plus the range will change depending on how the call to `xlswrite` is made.

Comment: So... is there a simple way to do it within the matlab m-file?  I will use VBA otherwise.